# Python: What is the simples way to compare two numbers (in tuple) returned by a function?

Tags: python-2.7

Consider a function that returns two numbers:

```
def func():
    # ....
    return a,b
```

What is the simplest way to apply the compare operator `==` to the result of the function?

I've tried with `lambda` but I'm looking for something simple:-

```
q = lambda x, y: x == y
[q(*func()) for i in range(16)]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The shortest way I can think of is to check

```
len(set(func())) == 1
```

(works without caveats because you said they were two numbers, so hashable)

But I would personally just assign the result of the function to a variable and then do it the normal way.

Edit: ohh, now I understand your lambda; it already exists as `operator.eq`:

```
from operator import eq

eq(*func())
```

Is rather neater.

Answer (score 0):

If you can modify `func()` then you can add a third return value to it that would indicate if the first two return values are equal,

```
from random import randint

def fun():
    a = randint(0,5)
    b = randint(0,5)
    return a, b, a == b

res = [fun()[2] for i in range(10)]
```

If you can't modify `func()` then you can also use a decorator, though it is not really simpler, maybe just more robust and clear than the lambda:

```
from random import randint

def elem_equal(func):
    def wrapper():
        a,b = func()
        return a == b
    return wrapper

@elem_equal
def fun():
    a = randint(0,5)
    b = randint(0,5)
    return a, b

res = [fun() for i in range(10)]
```

The decorator `elem_equal` calls the target function `func()` and returns comparison of its return values.